# Need to convert a $_FILES to $_POST in php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have to input fields like

```
<input id="input_A" type="file" multiple="" onchange="doitgood();" />
<input id="input_B" type="text" />
```

and

```
function doitgood(){
    document.getElementById('input_B').value=document.getElementById('input_A').value;
}
```

but in the end it only copies one file and not all files separated by comma.
`input_bB also could be hidden which is much better.

The reason I need this because I need my file (`$_FILES`) list also as `$_POST` to retrieve some extra data.

The problem is I need the exact same string from `A` to `B`.

Comment: What is the "extra data" you are trying to retrieve ?

Comment: I need it for a workaround to get original timestamp of the file

Comment: Why not just merge these 2 arrays? (array_merge)

Comment: @seot: A workaround for what?  How are you getting the timestamps?

Comment: there is a function getting the full file location and get by exif_read_data only getting in the array["FileDateTime"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Jquery map() function to get exactly what you wanted (hidden input containing csv list value)

```
<script>
$(function(){  
    var filelist;
     $("#input_A").change(function () {
       filelist = $.map($('#input_A').get(0).files, function (file, i) {
            return file.name;
        });
        var fileinput = $('<input/>',{type:'hidden',id:'input_B',name:'input_B',value:filelist});
        fileinput.appendTo('#form1');       
    });
});

</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/js5AW/

Comment: but how it could save the full location of the file?

Comment: @seot - You can't get the full path from a file input in new browsers for security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
    function doitgood(){   
    var str = '';
    var files = document.getElementById("input_A").files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
        str += files[i].name;
    }
 document.getElementById('input_B').value=str;
 }
</script>
```

Comment: but in input A its the full location and in input B only the filename. I need the exact same on both fields. also the file location.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [FileList API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) to get the names and modification dates of your files.

```
function doitgood(){
    var files = document.getElementById('input_A').files,
        inputB = document.getElementById('input_B'),
        fileNames = [], fileDates = [];

    for(var i = 0, len = files.length; i < len; i++){
        var file = files[i];
        fileNames.push(file.name);
        fileDates.push(+file.lastModifiedDate);
    }

    inputB.value = fileNames.join(',');
    console.log(fileDates);
}
```

This should work in any "modern browser" (so, not IE <= 9).

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/bA9Hm/1/

Comment: but can't show or save file.lastModifiedDate somewhere? need it in php

Comment: @seot: Just put it in another `<input>` like you did with the file name.

Comment: but the second input_b has than a [object FileList] in it. how can I resolve this after on submit in PHP

Comment: @seot: How are you setting the input?  You want to use the `.name` or `.lastModifiedDate` property of the file object, not the object itself.